How does this keyword work in abstract class
I know that private field are not inherited, and when I am creating an object at line #2, the object is being created for Person and then when I set the fatherName, inside the setFatherName() how is this "which is object of person" has the visibility to set Test class private fatherName?
abstract  class  Test {
    private String fatherName ;

    public void setFatherName(String fatherName){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        this.fatherName=fatherName;
    }
    public String getFatherName(){
       return  fatherName;
    }
}

public class Person extends  Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test person = new Person(); // #2
        person.setFatherName("Jimmy");
        System.out.println("father name is : " +person.getFatherName());

    }
}

Output :
Person
father name is : Jimmy

I understand the context that I am indirectly doing it with a setter, but how does this keyword work here in abstract class since object is Person?

for the compiler this is of type Test; not the same as the result of calling this.getClass() -- you could even have declared the method as public void setFatherName(Test this, String fatherName){ -- BTW abstract does not matter in that

It works because the setter is inherited, which is marked as public. The variables are actually "inherited" too (meaning that they have a place allocated in the memory), even if they are marked as private. You just cannot directly access them from the child class.
Accessing them using a public method, as you do here, is allowed. The setter you are calling is actually called inside the superclass. If you had overridden it, you wouldn't have access to this.fatherName inside the child class. You should have delegated the setting logic to the parent.
But using a setter should work. Better to mark your field as protected, though, in order to respect encapsulation. I consider that inside the class hierarchies, direct access to the variable should be prioritized over public methods, while setters should be used for access from outside.

just that i get this right , child class object still have access to parent private variables even though they are not inherited. Got it . was having a tough time understanding context of this keyword inside abstract class and private variables

They do not have access to private variables. Private variables are only accessible from the classes they are defined in. But those variables are actually allocated in memory for child classes, too. That's what I was talking about

If you call a setter from on child class, if it's not overridden, the setter will execute the logic from the parent class, which has direct access to the private variable. And that should work without any issues

So directly accessing a private variable (defined in a parent class) from a child class will result in a compilation error!

@RishabNegi In other words, private means private.
